# Perl regular expression regarding maximum length of characters

Tags: perl, expression, maxlength

I am trying to create a Perl validation expression for the maximum length allowed for a given string (in a specific interface)

I tried `/.{0,5}/` or `/^.{0,5}&/` that I noticed was used in many similar cases, but it seems that any entered string (even below 20 characters) fails...

I have searched & tested many many ways, but with no result.

I recently tried:

`[[:alpha:]]\{0,20\}`

But the behavior was very strange...

How can I fix this? I am just interesting in preventing the user from entering 20 or more characters in the form.

Comment: How do you use the regular expression to validate the string?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a regex, try with the `length()` function.

Example:

```
my $max = 4;
my $input = "qwerty";
if (length($input) < $max) {
    print "[$input] is less than $max\n";
} 
else {
    print "[$input] is more or equal than $max\n";
}
```

See

```
perldoc -f length
```

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. If you think that the answer is well answerred, you can 'accept' it by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are reading input from the command line:

```
#!/usr/perl/bin -w

use strict;

my $input;
while (1) {
    $input = <>;
    if(length($input) < 20) {
        print "perfect\n";
    } 
    else {
        print "Exceeded 20 characters\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually searching for an regular expression (like /^.{1,20}$/) & not for a code like this. The pearl file were I insert the validation expression is read and the expression allows or not the input

Answer (score 0):

Use `/^.{1,20}$/`:

```
$ echo "12345678901234567890123" | perl -nle "print if /^.{1,20}$/"

$ echo "12345678901234567890" | perl -nle "print if /^.{1,20}$/"
12345678901234567890
```

Comment: I am sorry - i mistyped... I meant to write /^.{1,20}$/. (This is what i tried)
It did not work... It allows every entry...